# Codeigniter email class not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried the code below. At one time the code was working fine. I was able to send the emails. After a few minutes, when I tried it again without even changing anything, I get this error message `Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.`

I dont know whats wrong. Lately I am facing a lot of similar bugs with codeigniter.

```
public function email($message = NULL, $subject=NULL, $email=NULL){
        if(!isset($email)){
            $to = $this->session->userdata('email');
        }else{
            $to = $email;
        }
        $this->load->library('email');


        $this->email->from('noreply@mydomain.com', 'Mydomain');
        $this->email->to($to); 

        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);    

        $this->email->send();
    }
```

Comment: The framework doesn't "die" over time, without changing anything. Is it possible your session expired, and the `$to` variable became empty? That could cause an error.

Comment: Did you check you server and php configurations ?

Comment: @OliverNagy Even if I pass a email variable to that function,  I am getting the same error.

Comment: @safarov I never changed anything. It was just working fine few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

i face this problem and work hard and i find solution this

just little change in email config its working 100%

---

```
 $config['protocol'] = 'ssmtp';
 $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://ssmtp.gmail.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines and the mail is working again.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
            $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

            $this->email->initialize($config);
```